# How I write php code for auto colour changing?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a table in MySQL name `'contact number'`. From where I want to display `'c_n'` field's data . If the fields value is less or more than 11 digit then the field's color needs to turn red and value is equal to 11 digit, color needs to change green. Now how can I write the PHP code for solving it?

The code:

```
switch($row['c_n']) {
    case($row['c_n'] > "11"):
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td font color="red">
                <?php echo"'c_n";?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?
```

Comment: please past your PHP file code here.

Comment: switch($row['c_n']){case($row['c_n']>"11"):?><tr><td font color="red"><?php echo"'c_n";?></td></tr><?

Comment: Edit your answer, and put it there. Format it properly too, by highlighting the code in your question, and press the `{}` in the editor.

Comment: @Shyful please, edit your question by adding the core there, and use code formatting, because then it will be much more readable. 
And then describe, what exactly does not work with that piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is the following:"

```
<?php
$color = "black";
if(strlen($row['c_n']) > 11){
    $color = "red";
}
?>
<tr>
    <td style="color:<?php echo $color; ?>>
        <?php echo $row['c_n']; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

which could be shortened to the following with some shorthands:

```
<tr>
    <td style="color:<?=(strlen($row['c_n'])) > 11 ? "red" : "black"; ?>>
        <?=$row['c_n']?>
    </td>
</tr>
```